# I should receive form entries to google sheet though appscript only if a customer pays online

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, payment-gateway

I have a form connected to google sheet through app script. Once the user fills in the form, they have to pay online to complete registration. But some users don't pay after filling up the form. Is there any way method to get form entries only if the user pays?

I tried adding the payment link before receiving form submission in the script but didn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var script_url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwxw9ih26z2B5eS_68qfR6CRmQUgZRnNXedW5CjpCS5IwukkWg/exec";
        function insert_value() {
            var id              = $("#id").val();
            var full_name       = $("#full_name").val();
            var studying_class  = $("#studying_class").val();
            var school_name     = $("#school_name").val();
            var contact_no      = $("#contact_no").val();
            var e_mail_address  = $("#e_mail_address").val();
            var gender          = $("#gender").val();
            var dob             = $("#dob").val();
            var url = script_url + "?callback=ctrlq&full_name=" + full_name + "&id=" + id + "&contact_no=" + contact_no + "&studying_class=" + studying_class + "&school_name=" + school_name + "&e_mail_address=" + e_mail_address + "&gender=" + gender + "&dob=" + dob + "&action=insert";
            var request = jQuery.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
            $("#registration-form")[0].reset();
            // var message = 'We will contact you through your contact no provided.';
            // $('#alertModal').find('.modal-body p').text(message);
            // $('#alertModal').modal('show')
            // https://paytm.business/link/1570965263162/LL_16421645
            window.location.href = "https://paytm.business/link/1570965263162/LL_16421645";
        }
        function ctrlq(e) {
            alert("Successfully Registered")
        }
</script>
```

Should get form entries in google sheet through the app script only if the user pays online.

Comment: On the way how you wrote this code, there is not possibility to check  if the customer paid or not.. you should think to use the payment solution API or something like this.
You need to answer at this question to find the solution : "How I know when the customer paid me?"

Comment: I get email notification. And also the form entries. We had a tough time to match the payments found in the gateway dashboard and the form entries.

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation flow, what you describe is not possible. However, you can follow the steps detailed in the *paytm* custom checkout documentation: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/custom-checkout/

The idea is that after the ["Process transaction API"](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/process-transaction-api) is called, it returns whether the transaction has failed or has been approved. You can then use that information to decide whether you want your data to be submitted into your application or not.

Comment: so, i should use the developer options and contact the payment gateway to get this done?

Comment: @Balachandiran correct, using the developers API you have to contact the gateway before sending your forn request. Note that this will also make it easier to match a transaction and a form entry, since you will get a transaction identifier that you can send along with the form.

Comment: Okay got it, transaction identifier (the payment ID can be sent along with my form right)

Comment: @Balachandiran yes! That is the field that will help you easily join your form and payment gatway data.

Comment: Hey @Balachandiran, did you manage to find a solution? Please consider [voting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer in case it helped you, or tell me whether you found any other issue. Thanks !

Comment: I have contacted the payment gateway customer care. And I'm yet to receive a response. Will update soon. Thank you

Comment: i got reply from developers, but not sure which language coding to use, 

**
 
Developers (Instamojo)

Nov 18, 18:13 IST

Hi Bala,

We currently do not have a setup with Google sheet by which the data can be auto-populated. The article that you share requires coding to be done from your end to facilitate this. 

We will be able to provide the data that you require on your server-side.  From there, you will have to take it forward as per your needs. 

Hope this helps. Do let me know if you require further assistance from my end.
Regards,
Ajith
Tech Support
Instamojo**

Comment: @Balachandiran Since you are using a *GAS webapp* as a back-end, the code you to implement can be all in Javascript, and ran on the front-end of the application - just as you were doing. However, this time you will have to fetch the transaction identifier along with other information of the payment, and submit it into your webapp. You can learn more about the flow here: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/custom-checkout/ Cheers